# Find centroid of disolved buffer zones

Tags: qgis, buffer, centroids

I've put a 20m buffer on all of my points (144,000 observations), dissolving all overlapping buffers.

How do I then take the centroid of the dissolved buffers in QGIS?

I want to reduce all overlapping areas to one point.

Comment: Is 'Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygon Centroids' not what you're after?

Comment: That gave me a single centroid for all the points, rather than a centroid for each individual buffer zone

Comment: Sound like the buffer is a multipart polygon if you're only getting a single centroid.  Try using Multi-part to Singles parts, then run centroid.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks, that's great. Want to put it as an answer and I'll mark it as  correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dissolving your buffer creates a multi-part polygon. Using the tool 'Polygon Centroids' will only create the centroid for that multi-polygon.  What you should do first is convert the multi-part using 'Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to Singleparts'.  Then run the centroid tool to create centroids for each individual buffer polygon.